# What does "weight(Synonym() )" mean in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch outputs following descriptions.

```
"description": "weight(Synonym(name.pinyin:w name.pinyin:wzry) in 232) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",



"description": "weight(name.completion:r in 232) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:"
```

I know weight(name.completion), but don't the one with `Synonym`?

Answer (score 0):

The second token is a synonym of the first.
You get a result if only one of the two tokens exists in the result.